# Unit test packages Maven style convention

Tags: python, unit-testing, coding-style, directory-structure, pybuilder

I want to create a pybuilder project with unit tests and packages. As an example, modified [simple python app](https://github.com/pybuilder/pybuilder/tree/master/samples/simple-python-app) example, with "helloworld" moved to package "hello".

My first instinct was to match the package structure with "main" and "unittest" sources:

```
+---src
   +---main
   |   \---python
   |       \---hello
   |               helloworld.py
   |               __init__.py
   |
   \---unittest
       \---python
           \---hello
                   helloworld_tests.py
                   __init__.py
```

This does not work because of conflicting "hello" package.

```
BUILD FAILED - 'module' object has no attribute 'helloworld_tests'
```

I see [pybuilder](https://github.com/pybuilder/pybuilder/tree/master/src) itself just skips the top-level pybuilder package in unittests, but won't do if there are multiple top-level packages.

My second guess would be to create extra top level package for unittests.

```
\---unittest
    \---python
        \---tests
            |   __init__.py
            \---hello
                    helloworld_tests.py
                    __init__.py
```

Is there a better solution or established convention how to organize python tests in packages?

Answer (score 2):

Probably nothing really new for the OP, but I just wanted to collect all options that I could come up with in one place:

**1) Just append `_tests` to names of top-level packages**

The easiest way to mirror the structure of `src/main/python` in the `src/test/python` almost 1:1 would be by simply appending `_tests` to the names of the top-level packages. For example, if I have only one top-level package `rootPkg`, then I can add the corresponding `rootPkg_tests` to the `test/` subdirectory:

```
src
├── main
│   ├── python
│   │   └── rootPkg
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── pkgA
│   │       │   ├── __init__.py
│   │       │   └── modA.py
│   │       └── pkgB
│   │           ├── __init__.py
│   │           └── modB.py
│   └── scripts
│       └── entryPointScript.py
└── test
    └── python
        └── rootPkg_tests
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── pkgA
            │   ├── __init__.py
            │   └── modA_tests.py
            └── pkgB
                ├── __init__.py
                └── modB_tests.py
```

This seems to work nicely with PyBuilder 0.11.15 and `unittest` plugin (notice that I've deviated from PyBuilders convention, and put tests in `test` instead of `unittest`, you probably shouldn't do this if you intend to use multiple testing frameworks).

**2) If there is only one package: do it like PyBuilder**

The PyBuilder is itself built with PyBuilder. This is what its source directory looks like (drastically reduced, unnecessary details omitted):

```
src
├── main
│   ├── python
│   │   └── pybuilder
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── cli.py
│   │       ├── core.py
│   │       └── plugins
│   │           ├── __init__.py
│   │           ├── core_plugin.py
│   │           └── exec_plugin.py
│   └── scripts
│       └── pyb
└── unittest
    └── python
        ├── cli_tests.py
        ├── core_tests.py
        ├── plugins
        │   ├── exec_plugin_tests.py
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── python
        │   │   ├── core_plugin_tests.py
        │   │   ├── __init__.py
```

If I understand it correctly, the tree in `unittest` mirrors the tree in `src`, but the directory for the top-level package `pybuilder` is omitted. That's what you have described in your question as first workaround. The drawback is that it doesn't really work if there are multiple top-level packages.

**3) Add one additional `tests` top-level package**

That's what you have proposed as a workaround: mirror the tree in `main`, but wrap everything in an additional `tests`-package. This works with many top-level packages in `/src/main/python` and prevents any package name collisions.

---

I'm not aware of any convention. Upvote one of the comments below if you have an opinion on that matter.